# How to embed a video into a PyQt Widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I have a PyQt GUI which currently has a button tied to a python function that opens a URL to a camera stream that I have over the web. So in its current state this opens up Edge via my Python function. Is there anything built inside of Qt designer that allows me to embed the stream in a Qt Widget? So from my GUI, just open a small window with the stream of my camera alone?

Comment: Use [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html), part of the QtWebEngineWidgets module.

Answer (score 0):

There is [QWebView](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/PyQt/qwebview.html) that can be used to load a webpage and display it in a PyQt GUI.

Comment: QWebView is part of the QtWebKit module, which is deprecated since 2015. Also, that documentation is outdated (and it's not even the official one). The correct widget to use is [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html), part of the QtWebEngineWidgets module.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at QWebView in PyQt
You might find the following link help [QWebView - pythoncentral](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-qwebview/)

Comment: QWebView is part of the QtWebKit module, which is deprecated since 2015. The correct widget to use is [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html), part of the QtWebEngineWidgets module.